# Identifying a Distinct Count for a Column Without Using Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to get the distinct count of something that's conditional and doesn't use group by. I've got a table that has columns as seen here:

Employeeid, Training_Course_name, CompletedDate

Some of the courses have the word Rope in them. 
I want to take the number of completed courses per person with the word "Rope" in the title and divide it by the number of unique courses there are that have the word rope in the title. If there are 15 unique course names that have the word rope in the title, regardless of who they're assigned to, I want to come up with that number and have it divided into the number of completed rope courses per person.

Comment: why is group by not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(distinct case when Training_Course_name like '%rope%'
                           then Training_Course_name
             end) as courses_with_rope
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to solve your problem

```
Declare @UniqueCourses As TABLE(Course As VarChar(32))

Select @UniqueCourses = Training_Course_Name 
From
    (SELECT DISTINCT Training_Course_Name 
    FROM Employess 
    WHERE Training_Course_Name LIKE '%Rope%') A 

SELECT 
EmpId,
     (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Employees innerEmployees
      WHERE innerEmployees.EmpId = outerEmployees.EmpId AND 
      innerEmployees.CompletedDate is not null
     ) AS Completed Courses
From Employees outerEmployees
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the course with the word rope in them with this query

```
SELECT Employeeid, Training_Course_name, CompletedDate
FROM Table_Name_You_Did_Not_Say
WHERE Training_Course_name LIKE '%rope%'
```

And a distinct count like this

```
SELECT Employeeid, Training_Course_name, CompletedDate, 
       count(distinct Training_Course_name) as distinct_names
FROM Table_Name_You_Did_Not_Say
WHERE Training_Course_name LIKE '%rope%'
```

Anything "by employee id" would require a group by -- so what exactly is your requirement?